# ModelingToolkit: 2nd order differential equation and equivalent 1st order system give different answers

Tags: julia, differential-equations, differentialequations.jl

I am trying to solve a 2nd order differential equation with ModelingToolkit.jl in Julia:

```
using ModelingToolkit
using DifferentialEquations: solve
using Plots: plot

@variables s ρ(s) Dρ(s)
@parameters N,M,Λ
D = Differential(s)

ω = sqrt(N - 1)*N/(N*(4*N*s^2 - 4*N*s + N - 4*s^2 + 4*s))
eqn = D(D(ρ)) ~ -4*ω*ρ

@named eqnODE = ODESystem([eqn],s)
```

I seem to get very different answers depending on whether I run

```
sol1 = solve(ODEProblem(eqnODE, [ρ => 0.5, D(ρ) => 0], (0.0,1.0), [N => 10000]))
```

or

```
lowered_eqnODE = ode_order_lowering(eqnODE)
sol2 = solve(ODEProblem(lowered_eqnODE, [ρ => 0.5, D(ρ) => 0], (0.0,1.0), [N => 10000]))
```

How is this possible? My first thought would be that I messed up the parameters, but I think I'm doing the same as here: https://mtk.sciml.ai/dev/tutorials/higher_order/

Here are the two plots:
Plot of sol1
[image: Plot of sol1]
Plot of sol2 (1st order system)
[image: Plot of sol2 (1st order system)]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: See https://github.com/SciML/ModelingToolkit.jl/issues/1389